# Unable to link QtFFmpegWrapper sample on Win7 with VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, linker, ffmpeg, qt5

I am trying to incorporate QtFFmpegWrapper in my program, but both my program and the provided sample won't link with ffmpeg:

```
QVideoEncoder.obj:-1: Error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _avcodec_init referenced in function "protected: bool __thiscall QVideoEncoder::initCodec(void)" (?initCodec@QVideoEncoder@@IAE_NXZ)
QVideoDecoder.obj:-1: Error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _avcodec_init
QVideoEncoder.obj:-1: Error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _avcodec_thread_init referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QVideoEncoder::createFile(class QString,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?createFile@QVideoEncoder@@QAE_NVQString@@IIIII@Z)
QVideoEncoder.obj:-1: Error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _avcodec_open referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall QVideoEncoder::createFile(class QString,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int,unsigned int)" (?createFile@QVideoEncoder@@QAE_NVQString@@IIIII@Z)
```

and 10 or so more like these ...

Why do these pop up when linking ? The libs are all there and found, it just seems like the linker has issues with them ...

I use the following setup for my project:

- Latest QtFFmpegWrapper from https://code.google.com/p/qtffmpegwrapper/
- qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2012_opengl-5.3.0
- Visual Studio 2012 Professional
- Qt Creator 3.1.2
- ffmpeg builds from http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/:
- ffmpeg-20140717-git-fa6716c-win32-dev
- ffmpeg-20140717-git-fa6716c-win32-shared

Everything is 32Bit.

Comment: Have you found the solution, I am having the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your question. I found no solution that worked for linking directly, now I use an external ffmpeg with QProcess.